# The request failed with HTTP status 417: Expectation failed

Tags: vb.net, http

Without getting into much detailed code 
I have an 'kiosk' application that is running in about 500-800 different 'kiosk' at about 50 locations. Very simple application that connects to internet via a Verizon MIFI (2-3 MIFI per location).  We believe that Verizon has made some changes to the network and now randomly I get

> The request failed with HTTP status 417: Expectation failed

I have viewed [The request failed with HTTP status 417: Expectation Failed - Using Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198393/the-request-failed-with-http-status-417-expectation-failed-using-web-services)
and [FB Connect: (417) Expectation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468510/fb-connect-417-expectation-failed)

But you see I already had used

```
  System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false
```

in my code.

So one of the issues I have is the application isn't easy to test, and it will fail for 20-30 minutes or several days, then clears itself up.

Changing the config to include

```
<system.net>
<settings>
    <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
</settings>
```

Would be a large task, I don't know it that would even fix it.  Since it is random I'm having troubles because I typically can't get it to fail in my office at my desk more than 1 time.

I happen to use VB and .Net for the application and services that run with the 'kiosk'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the config on the mifi and not the Verizon network itself.  We recently switched APNs and when a mifi connects to the Verizon network it is supposed to update automatically.  Sometimes the mifi will fail to update the APN setting and that is when we get this error message.  There are two ways I have found to fix this issue.  The first and easier is to log into the mifi and manually update the setting.  If you are dealing with a user who is not tech savvy and walking them through logging into the mifi will not work you can call the Verizon wireless enterprise help desk and have them remove the feature set from the mifi, add the features back, and then pull the battery from the mifi and power cycle it, this will make the mifi request the configuration settings again.